# SQL help - clear all the values of a specific field

Tags: query, sql

We ran a batch import to pull in several hundred entries, but some fields got imported incorrectly. For example, all the websites imported as "link", when they should have been blank.

Can someone help me with a command to run in the SQL manager that will clear all the values of a custom field?

EE2.10.1, Channel ID 9, Field ID 60

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This'll do it. However, as always... **back up your exp_channel_data table** before doing anything, especially if you're not a developer or DB admin.

```
UPDATE exp_channel_data 
    SET field_id_60 = ""
    WHERE channel_id = "9";
```

Comment: perfect! fixed several hundred entries in seconds.